# square connect v2 payment form not working in safari and opera browsers

Tags: square

I have git the square connect v2 api working on chrome and IE11 so far for accepting card payments, however in the opera and safari browser the input fields can't be edited hence the payment won't work. Any ideas? The payment form is at https://theproservice.co.uk/. I'm coding in ASP.NET/C#/Javascript. Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: I just looked at your link with Safari 12 and it seems to work fine. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: hi, i think latest safari version on windows 7 is 5.7.1 and the fields are not editable on that. Is there a later version for windows 7? Google said i've got latest version of safari so not sure.

Comment: could just detect browser and say that version of safari not supported. Square should know better though. Only on windows is safari not being updated, however why would a windows user have safari. cheers for reply.

Comment: Did you get it working in Opera? what was the problem there?

Comment: Your link doesn't work